# Make rectangle with one side curved

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make a div same as this shape, if yes could you please share the code[image]

Comment: *if yes could you please share the code*: have you tried something?

Comment: I actually have an idea in mind that is:
a container div, white circle at right and a rectangle on left. When circle will intersect rectangle, it will look like this image.
But this idea would create border problems

I wanted to know whether we can apply css to just one div to achieve it

Comment: you might share anyway the code you tried and update your question. It can be useful for other answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `SVG`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdMVXY

```
<svg>
  <path d="M260 150, 0 150, 0 0, 300 0 Q260 75, 260 150" 
        stroke="transparent" fill="#bd9" />
</svg>
```

When you have defined the correct aspect ratio of the box, you can also scale the `SVG` element with a simple CSS transformation (as shown in the example)

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is possible within CSS using a single element with `pseudo-elements` with `border-radius` and `background-shadow` to create the curve.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -150%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200%;
  padding-bottom: 200%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px 300px #F15723;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px 300px #F15723;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make 'div' element:

```
<div id="test">
<div class="oposite-radius"></div>
```

```
<style>

#test {
position: relative;
margin: 30px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #333;
}

.oposite-radius {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 180px;
    border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
</style>
```